# In wordpress how do you write code that says "if this is a subcategory page ... display the name of the subcategory"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd imagen that it would look something like this:

```
<?php if (is_subcategory()): ?>
<h1><?php the_category(); ?></h1>
<?php else: ?>
<h1>something else</h1>
<?php endif ?>
```

Can someone tell me how this should actually be written?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if ( is_category() ) {
$child_cats = get_categories('child_of='.get_query_var('cat'));
}?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: so that's just to tell ask wordpress if it's in a subcat.  But then how do I print that subcat name?  is it still the_category();?